# AWS EC2 on Private Network

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I deployed a VPC, created a subnet for 192.168.0.0/16
Created its internet gateway as well.

Then I deployed a Windows EC2, assigned a elastic IP to it:
Private IP               Public IP
192.168.196.16           34.211.1.247

But I can't connect via RDP, the connection fails,

Any advise?
Thank you.

Comment: You need to update your security groups to allow RDP traffic

Comment: Did you configure an IG and routing properly on the VPC?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, since your instance have a public IP address, it is clear that it belongs to a public subnet. If you did not alter your Internet Gateway manually, it should work properly.

Next you should make sure that port **3389** of your EC2 instance is open to the CIDR block your IP address belongs to.

Try creating your CIDR block here http://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr

If it still does not work, can you confirm if your firewall settings allow it.

You can look up some troubleshooting tips here as well. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/troubleshooting-windows-instances.html#rdp-issues

To summarise them -

- Verify that you're using the correct public DNS hostname. (In the Amazon EC2 console, select the instance and check Public DNS (IPv4) in the details pane.) If your instance is in a VPC and you do not see a public DNS name, you must enable DNS hostnames. For more information, see Using DNS with Your VPC in the Amazon VPC User Guide.
- To connect to your instance using an IPv6 address, check that your local computer has an IPv6 address and is configured to use IPv6. If you launched an instance from a Windows Server 2008 SP2 AMI or earlier, your instance is not automatically configured to recognize an IPv6 address assigned to the instance. For more information, see Configure IPv6 on Your Instances in the Amazon VPC User Guide.
- Verify that your security group has a rule that allows RDP access. For more information, see Create a Security Group.
- If you copied the password but get the error Your credentials did not work, try typing them manually when prompted. It's possible that you missed a character or got an extra whitespace character when you copied the password.
- Verify that Windows Firewall, or other firewall software, is not blocking RDP traffic to the instance. We recommend that you disable Windows Firewall and control access to your instance using security group rules.